# Ubuntu 19.10... pixelsaver was working, but now isn't; reinstall doesn't work

Tags: gnome, 19.10, titlebar

Only been using Ubuntu for a couple weeks.

The amount of wasted space along the top of some windows is almost comical, but I realize that is largely due to the developers. For example, Chrome and Microsoft Teams make great use of the space. Firefox and Visual Studio Code... oof.

Trying to resolve this, I came across an answer on here suggesting `gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver`. Worked great for several days. Then just quit working yesterday. I've tried to `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver` and then reinstall. Restart, etc. Doesn't fix it.

I also tried [`no-title-bar`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/) and also made sure `x11-utils` was installed. Doesn't do anything either.

I haven't made any changes to the system, so I'm perplexed why it would just quit working.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

**EDIT - 3/27/20**

I ended up doing a reformat for a couple reasons, this being one of them.

Used this extension on the clean reformat:

https://github.com/pixel-saver/pixel-saver

Again... works for a few days and then stops working. Reinstalling it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get dconf editor and go to org->gnome->terminal->legacy->headerbar set to false. Then you can use the extension unite to e.g. remove titlebars when tiled of when the terminal fills the whole screen.

But but but I experience some glitches with the shadows behind the terminal when doing this. Maybe you wont. For now there is no other fixes.